# Connection Pooling in Node with Ioredis package

Tags: node.js, express, redis, azure-ad-msal, express-session

I am currently working on one project where we have used redis for session management (Express-session) and session contains important information which we are getting from Microsoft Authentication such as accessToken, tokenCache etc.

Now since we are using redis, everytime new user is accessing application new connection is being made to redis instance and will be active till session expires or logout. This causes peformance load on redis. so is connection pool solve this issue? I am new with redis on express application and not sure if its even possible to implement connection pool for redis on nodejs.

any helpful links / code snippets will be useful.

Checked the ioredis package / searched for connection pooling but not able to find anything strong which can be useful.